# How to run two Flask discord.py bots in the same repl.it project?

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

I am using repl.it to run two bots in the same repl and I'm using imports as a I saw in other stackoverflow questions.

```python
print('This will be the page where all bots will be made.')
import os
import bot1
import keep_alive
import bot2
import keep_alive1
while True:
  print('ALL BOTS STARTED!')
```

The problem is, it never gets to the `while` loop (it's for testing) because it gets stuck in the bot1 file. How should I fix this? **The reason I'm doing it in the same repl project is so I can merge the bot database.**

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using an SQLite or local database with repl.it. This is because when the containers do a restart you might lose some data (unless they have changed this over the years).

It is recommended to use a database like MongoDB which offers a free 500MB database for you to use.

Since you did ask a question, I will answer it. You could try this:

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(bot1.start("bot_token1"))
loop.create_task(bot2.start("bot_token2"))
loop.run_forever()
```

You would need to use cogs and have both bots set up in the `main.py` then use [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html) for better file management.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily use `asyncio` for this, `threading` or `multiprocessing` would be a better option. Though if the bots are small, this should do the trick

Comment: Well @ŁukaszKwieciński I based the asyncio usage on: hosting with repl.it your bot isn't going to be complex or require much bandwidth. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I don't even know why I put that there lmao

Comment: But, I am using a file database, txt files since I do not know how to use SQLite.
Right now, I'm creating text files with
```with open(str(ctx.author.id)+'.txt','w'):
   print('Testing', file=out)
```

Comment: He’s not telling you to use a database, he’s recommending. Though working with text files is a pain, you should switch to at least a json or yaml file

Comment: However, I used asyncio and it still isn't starting both. Also, I'm using keep_alive as my flask application and stuff. Here is the format I followed:  https://replit.com/talk/learn/Hosting-discordpy-bots-with-replit/11008
I used these files
• keep_alive1.py
• bot1.py
• keep_alive2.py
• bot2.py
and • main.py with `asyncio`.

Comment: Right, you need to understand that you need to put bot1.py and bot2.py into the main.py @NicholasWang

Comment: So merge them into **1 file?**

Comment: Yes @NicholasWang

Comment: Okay. This is the first time I'm doing this :) Thanks for y'all's support!

Comment: https://replit.com/@nicholasxwang/CHBUtils#main.py This isn't working though... To be honest, I am very confused now ;-;

Comment: @NicholasWang be patient. You need to understand there are different timezones in the world. This would be a separate question

Comment: @FluxedScript oh sry
btw im in  PDT rn

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use:

```
os.system(f"python {filename} &")
```

In the same script that your doing imports.
You just have to replace the **{filename}** with your file.

Imports just go to a file and doesn't leave that file.