# Discord.py: MissingRequiredArgument: self is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to change the presence when a user executes a command.
I have the Discord bot in an own Class. To change the presence I need the self argument.
But when I write

```py
    @bot.command()
    async def change(self, ctx):
        await self.client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("P-Hub"))
```

I get the Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.
```

And when I write:

```py
    @bot.command()
    async def change(ctx, self):
        await self.client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("P-Hub"))
```

I get this error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: self is a required argument that is missing.
```

The whole code is:

```py
    class DiscordBot():
        def __init__(self, client, token):
            self.client = client
            self.token = token

        def run(self):
            self.client.run(self.token)

       @bot.command()
            async def change(ctx, self):
                await self.client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("P-Hub"))

       @bot.event
           async def on_ready():
           print("My Ready is Body")

       @bot.listen()
           async def on_message(message):
               print(str(message.author) + ": " + message.content)

       if __name__ == '__main__':
           client = DiscordBot(bot, 'token')
           client.run()
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you put it in a class? It works fine when you leave it like the examples. If it's about running 2 bots in the same script then using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66625483/running-two-flask-discord-py-bots-in-the-same-repl-it-project/) will help you.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("My Ready is Body")

@bot.command()
async def change(ctx):
    await self.client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("P-Hub"))

bot.run('token')
```

If you need to use multiple files, have a look at [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html).